# Why is my If Statement in Bash not working?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ubuntu, if-statement

Hi I'm creating an archiving system in bash with a long and messy if statement which doesn't currently work with the current errors being on the last few lines with the else if statement. Although I expect there are further errors with this statement anyway. The variable choice is from a menu which displays in the terminal. So if they select option 1 the user then has to enter data to be written to the crontab file.

```
if [ $choice -eq "1" ] then
echo "Enter the MINUTE"
read  minute

    if [ $minute -eq 0 ] then
        GLOBIGNORE=*
        minute="*"
        echo minute
    fi

echo "Enter the Hour"
read hour

    if [ $hour -eq 0 ] then
        GLOBIGNORE=*
        hour="*"
        echo hour
    fi

echo "Enter the Day"
read day

    if [ $day -eq 0 ] then
        GLOBIGNORE=*
        day="*"
        echo day
    fi

echo "Enter the Month"
read month

    if [ $month -eq 0 ] then
        GLOBIGNORE=*
        month="*"
        echo month
    fi

echo "Enter the weekday"
read weekday

    if [ $weekday -eq 0 ] then
        GLOBIGNORE=*
        weekday="*"
        echo weekday
    fi


echo $minute $hour $day $month $weekday " date > ~/testcron.log" > testcron.txt fi
elif [ $choice -eq "2" ]
then
    echo "Enter the Source and Destination Locations"
fi
```

Comment: Please, fix the indentation. It should help you recognise the structure of the code, e.g. which `fi` belongs to which `if`.

Comment: Post the entire statement (I see multiple `if``s but only one `fi`).

Comment: bash is not python. indentation doesn't affect order-of-operations. NONE of your if statements have a terminating `fi`, so in effect you have a single series of deeply nested `if` statements.

Comment: Updated to include the fi statements, apologies for the formatting issue at the bottom the code won't paste straight in properly for some reason

Comment: You lack a newline before the `fi` right after writing the crontab file, is that a problem in your code or just a copy/paste error here? Also, for basic syntax checking, please try http://shellcheck.net/ before bothering the humans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with your code:

```
if [ $hour -eq 0 ] then
    GLOBIGNORE=*
    hour="*"
    echo hour
fi
```

In general (all test `[]`) are missing a `;` after it:

```
if [ $hour -eq 0 ]; then
```

The echo hour will not print the value of var hour but the word hour. Change to `echo "$hour"` (yes, quoted). Also, there is no need to set the variable GLOBIGNORE to `*` if vars are properly quoted.

The vars here are not quoted, that is a reason for it to fail (or to need GLOBIGNORE):

```
echo $minute $hour $day $month $weekday
```

Change to:

```
echo "$minute $hour $day $month $weekday"
```

The redirection on that same line is a plain `>`, that will empty the file.
If you want to append to the files, do as this:

```
echo "$minute $hour $day $month $weekday" "$(date >> ~/testcron.log)" >>testcron.txt
```

In that line there is an unneeded additional fi

This script may be of help:

```
get(){
    read -p "$1" "$2"
    if [ "$((${!2}))" -eq 0 ]; then
        eval "$2"="*"
        echo "${!2}"
    fi
}

read -p "Choice?:" choice

if [ "$choice" -eq "1" ]; then
    get "Enter the MINUTE"  minute
    get "Enter the Hour"    hour
    get "Enter the Day"     day
    get "Enter the Month"   month
    get "Enter the weekday" weekday
    date >> ~/testcron.log
    echo "$minute $hour $day $month $weekday" >> testcron.txt
elif [ "$choice" -eq "2" ]; then
    echo "Enter the Source and Destination Locations"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a semi-colon:

```
if [ $choice -eq "1" ]; then
```

or

```
if [ $choice -eq "1" ] 
then
```

A semi-colon or a newline is required because the *command* is actually `[` and has to be terminated after the `]`, which is just the last argument given to `[`.

That is the old `test` (or `[`) syntax, you could also use:

```
if (( choice == 1 ))
then
```